# Reducers in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have just started learning to react and redux. I was just wondering how should I create my multiple reducers? Should my reducers be based on my action type? for example, if I have a e-commerce web, one reducer should be for adding, removing and updating to cart. Another reducer will be for clicking an item an displaying the information. It is supposed to be like that I assume.

Comment: You could start from here to fully consume the concept of redux(https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start). After that, head over here to get an example of e-commerce implementation from them(https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples/#shopping-cart)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple objects in a reducer to point your different needs. Your component can then listen to the changes of that particular object alone. You should make use of the method *combineReducers* from redux to achieve this.
Use this link *https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers/* to explore more about it.